# How to transform excel formulas back into text strings?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wish to compare the formulas in some excel sheets.

How can I transform all the formulas in a sheet to strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text of a formula as a string you can use the `FORMULATEXT` function, for example if you want to search for the position of a certain part of the formula. This sounds closest to what you are asking.

```
=FORMULATEXT(A1)
```

However if you just want to be able to see the formulae, you can toggle the display to show all formulae in the sheet at once using the shortcut:

```
Ctrl + `
```

or on a Mac:

```
Cmd + `
```

That ` is the accent key (top left on my keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to just see the formula what is written, then you can see the same in the Formula bar on the top.

or

if you want to check all the formulae in all cells.
Select the calculated result cells that you want to convert to text string.

Replace = sign with '=  (i.e. adding a comment to the formula)

Then click Replace All button, you can see all the calculated results are replaced with the original formula text strings